# Check array values, if are present in mongodb collection push into new array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I connect to mongodb both directly and with mongoose, mongoose db file gets called via `dbConnect()` and the queries i do work fine. The problem is with the standard db connection I added later, (`const { db } = await connectToDatabase();`) to query a collection that I can't translate into an acceptable mongoose schema.

my code at the top:

```
import { connectToDatabase } from "../../utils/mongodb"
import dbConnect from '../../utils/dbConnect'

dbConnect();

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();

  try{ ...
```

I fetch some `data` from an API
and i need to iterate through this `data.title` s and do a `find()` in a mongodb collection "channels" (field is "name") in order to keep only those data.title s which match collection items' field name

What i tried is this:

```
        var token = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&mine=true&maxResults=50&key=${process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY}&access_token=${token}`;
        token = token.replace(/"/g, '');

        var url = await fetch(token);
        const subsData = await url.json();

        //* Save all followed channels names, imgs and ids in arrays
        var subsArray = [], idsArray = [], imgsArray = [];
        for(let i=0; i < subsData.items.length; i++){
          //* check the channel's name is in database
          // if ( Chann.findOne({ "name" : subsData.items[i].snippet.title }) ) {
          if ( db.channels.find({ name: subsData.items[i].snippet.title }) != null ) {
            idsArray.push(subsData.items[i].snippet.resourceId.channelId);
            subsArray.push(subsData.items[i].snippet.title);
            imgsArray.push(subsData.items[i].snippet.thumbnails.default.url);
          }
        }
```

but it throws: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`

As you can see from the code I also tried with mongoose instead, both are configured in my project, but with mongoose schema it simply did nothing, as if the `findOne` was always true. So it didn't throw any error but basically didn't work, all channels in array were accepted. I wonder if this happened cause of a imperfect match between schemas, since i recreated manually the schema "Chann" from the mongodb data that was already there, and i'm not 100% sure i wrote array's objects correctly here and there..

**UPDATE**:

as suggested below I changed it to be:

```
  var subsArray = [], idsArray = [], imgsArray = [];
  for(let i=0; i < subsData.items.length; i++){
  
  console.log("title "+subsData.items[i].snippet.title)
  
  const result = await db.collection("Channels").find({ name: subsData.items[i].snippet.title })
  console.log("result "+result)
  if(!result.length) {
    idsArray.push(subsData.items[i].snippet.resourceId.channelId);
    subsArray.push(subsData.items[i].snippet.title);
    imgsArray.push(subsData.items[i].snippet.thumbnails.default.url);
  }
}
```

but what it logs is an `[object Object]` , if i add to the find line `.toArray()` it becomes a `[object promise]` and if i try to log `JSON.stringify` the `result` it throws TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: Have you tried [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)?

Comment: I didn't even know of it, looks interesting. Althoug the issue here i think is the database call, in fact the const which should contain an array logs an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.channels.find({ name: subsData.items[i].snippet.title }) != null
```

This will not work the way you are using it.

```
db.channels.find({ name: subsData.items[i].snippet.title })
```

Returns a `Promise` which will never be `null`.

Instead you'll want to do something like

```
const result = await db.channels.find({ name: subsData.items[i].snippet.title })
if(!result.length) {
   ...
}
```

You can you use callbacks, Promises, or async/await to wait for the db result, my example was using `async/await` but there are options.

Comment: I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined" the collection name is Channels with capped C, so in the code I used "db.Channels.find"

Comment: but i think I can't use await inside a loop? the loop goes on and the awaits accumulate i guess, if there's a way to save all collection "name" values inside an array prior to the loop i maybe can do a if array.includes for each index of the loop?

Comment: and if i use "db.collection("Channels").find" instead, it pushes all channels regardless, even those which don't match the collection "name". I'm debugging the result and it seems an object, but when i use JSON.stringify its throws TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: @m4tt you can use await inside of a loop. The for loop will pause.

It looks like you are probably using the mongo driver directly, instead of mongoose. If you are using the driver directly you'll want to do  `.find(...).toArray()`. Mongoose does this automatically. I wrote my answer assuming you were using Mongoose.

Comment: It actually works, was a stupid error in the env.local by my side. Please edit it a bit so i'm going to upvote it and make it the answer

Answer (score 0):

First check -

```js
if(subsData.items[i].snippet.title!= undefined && subsData.items[i].snippet.title!= null){
    // ....
}else{
    console.log(...);
}
```

Comment: i'm logging it and the value is ok